# Rails Memchached Failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, memcached, rubygems

I work on a project which is coded with Rails 2.3.14 and Ruby 1.8.7. I have a problem is about Memcached. After I run rails server, I write localhost:3000 on my browser but the error messages "Internal Server Error" returns with `#<ActionController::Session::MemCacheStore:0x10ed4aee0> unable to find server during initialization.`

I've tried [Rails, Passenger and Memcached: Unable to find server during initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2930249/rails-passenger-and-memcached-unable-to-find-server-during-initialization)

But it didnt work.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Try to find out if memcached is really running, for example by [using telnet](http://lzone.de/articles/memcached.htm), by a ps command

```
$ ps aux | grep memcached
```

or by checking the daemon directly:

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/memcached status
 * memcached is running
```

If it is not running, start it (or else restart it):

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/memcached start
```

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem running memcached. But I want to run server without running memcached.